# When binding a single click event to multiple buttons, how can I make the clicked button do one thing and all the other buttons do another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've got three buttons within a ui-grid-b

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><button id="btnOvenA" style="width:100%" value="a">A</button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><button id="btnOvenB" style="width:100%" value="b">B</button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><button id="btnOvenC" style="width:100%" value="c">C</button></div>
</div>
```

whenever a button is clicked, I want to turn its text red.  I want to turn the others text blue.  My click event currently looks like this:

```
$("#btnOvenA, #btnOvenB, #btnOvenC").click(function (event) {
   oven += $(event.target).attr('value');
   $(this).closest('div .ui-grid-b').css('color', 'blue');
   $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

It's not working.  My idea is, before the clicked button is turned red, turn all of the buttons blue, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.  My thought for the third line is to find the closest div with class `.ui-grid-b`, turn them all blue, and then just change the one I clicked to red.

I know one way would be to individually set each button to blue and then clicked to red, but I want this to work if there are 100 buttons, and I don't want to have to handcode every single line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You can make all button in `ui-grid-b` div to blue and make clicked button to red

```
$("#btnOvenA, #btnOvenB, #btnOvenC").click(function (event) {
   oven += $(event.target).attr('value');
   //make all button blue first
   $(this).closest('div.ui-grid-b').find('button').css('color', 'blue');
   //make clicked button red
   $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qLb6yfbt/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
$(".ui-grid-b button").click(function (event) {
  $(".ui-grid-b button").not(this).css('color', 'blue');
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qLb6yfbt/)**

Comment: Almost like yours! :D :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `blue` to all. Add `red` specifically to the clicked button.

```
$("#btnOvenA, #btnOvenB, #btnOvenC").click(function (event) {
    $("[id^=btnOven]").not(this).css("color","blue");
    $(this).css("color","red");
});
```

**NOTE -** Not sure about how well the code is going to perform.

**FIDDLE -** http://jsfiddle.net/w0gqo6hs/